# how to "data" to JSON results string in MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-4

My controller returning simple JSON results. how can I add `{ "data":` in JSON.?

```
var result = new JsonNetResult
          {
              Data = reportSubmittedAbstracts,
              JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet,
              Settings = { ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore }
          };
          string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(reportSubmittedAbstracts); ;
          return result;


$.get(url, null, function (data) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    table = $('#tblReports').DataTable({
       "data": data,
       "columns": [
              { "data": "MeetingCode" },
              { "data": "TitleInLanguage" },
              { "data": "TitleInEnglish" },
              { "data": "AbstractText" },
              { "data": "FirstCategory" },
              { "data": "SecondCategory" },
              { "data": "PrimaryAuthor.Name" },
              { "data": "PrimaryAuthor.Company" },
              { "data": "PrimaryAuthor.Country" },
              {
                 "class": 'details-control',
                 "orderable": false,
                 "data": null,
                 "defaultContent": ''
                }
            ],
           "order": [[1, 'asc']]
         });
```

`alert(JSON.stringify(data));` is printing

`[{"MeetingCode":"2014","TitleInLanguage":"Title (in Russian)","TitleInEnglish":" Title  (in English)","AbstractText":"Abstract Text","FirstCategory":"бурение",
        "SecondCatgory":"трещиноватость","PrimaryAuthor":{"Name":"sri vad",
         "Company":null,"Country":"usa"},"SecondaryAuthor":[{"Name":"sdfsad 
         vad","Company":null,"Country":"usa"}]`

But I am expecting `{ "data": [{"MeetingCode":"2014","TitleInLanguage":"Title (in Russian)... }]}`

Comment: Probably because your `reportSubmittedAbstracts` variable doesn't have a `data` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var result = new JsonNetResult
{
    Data = new { data = reportSubmittedAbstracts },
    JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet,
    Settings = { ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore }
};
return result;
```